# Summing vectors with common lisp 'loop' macro

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I need to implement something like this:

```
(loop for i from 1 to N sum (f i))
```

except that accumulated values are represent lists of numbers like (1 2 3)
and they are added element-wise. In other words I would like to initialize summation
with (zerov N) and use (v+) to add subsequent elements:

```
(defun v+ (a b) (mapcar '+ a b))
(defun zerov (n) (loop for i from 1 to n collect 0))
```

Is it possible to do something like this with loop macro? I can implement it as a 
separate function, but I would like to use loop or loop-like macro for expressiveness.
Perhaps there is a way to define simple loop-like macro just for this case?

Comment: Standard LOOP doesn't provide any way for users to customize the operations, but there may be implementation-specific extensions that allow this (the earlier MacLisp LOOP allowed user-defined operators, and some implementations may have built on that code).

Comment: I am using CCL. I do not see anything there I can use.

Comment: `(mapcar `+ a b)` is instantly recognizable for what it is. However, it commits your representation of vectors to lists. The best thing to do is to abstract the vector operations behind a vector API. In your own package, you can bind the `+` operator to a function that can add two vectors (and still works for numbers, and possibly combinations of numbers and vectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOOP` as defined in the Common Lisp standard is not extensible.

I would write it with the normal LOOP functionality:

```
(let ((result (zerov n)))
  (loop for i from 1 to N
        do (setf result (v+ result (f i))))
  result)
```

The I would write it as a function:

```
(defun sum (n f init sum)
  (let ((result (funcall init n)))
    (loop for i from 1 to n
          do (setf result (funcall sum result (funcall f i))))
    result))
```

If you want such a functionality as a direct language feature of a loopy macro, then an alternative would be the [ITERATE](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) macro, which is more powerful than the LOOP macro and it is also extensible.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this solution. It is probably too much to ask, but I am coming from Haskell world and would be much happier with pure-functional solution, something like high-level reduce...

Comment: @krokodil: using CL:REDUCE for this makes no sense in Common Lisp. Better stick with a loop implementation and provide it as a function.

Comment: @krokodil: Given your definition of `v+`, and a suitable definition of range, you could write `(reduce #'v+ (mapcar #'f (range 1 n)))`

Answer (score 3):

```
(loop with accum = (make-list n :initial-element 0)
      for i from 1 to n
    do (setq accum (v+ accum (f i)))
  finally (return accum))
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you are missing closing bracket at "do" line

Answer (score 0):

```
(reduce #'v+ (loop for i from 1 to n collect (f i))
        :initial-value (zerov n))
```

Note that Common Lisp has proper "vector" (i.e., sequence of elements of homogeneous type allowing more compact representation and efficient random access), so perhaps,

```
(defun v+ (a b) (map-into a #'+ a b))
(defun zerov (n) (make-array n :initial-element 0))
(defun fn (i n) (let ((v (zerov n))) (setf (aref v i) 1) v))
(defun gn (n)
  (loop for v = (zerov n) then (v+ v (fn i n)) for i below n
        finally (return v)))
```

Comment: The problem with the REDUCE is that lists in Lisp are not lazy and you need to pass the full list to reduce.